# Вопрос про адаптивный дизайн

Tags: html, css

Недавно начал изучать адаптивный дизайн и возник теоретический вопрос:
Является ли сайт адаптивным (или же отзывчивым) если у него есть горизонтальная полоса прокрутки(к примеру тот же stackoverflow). У самого в учебной верстке все элементы обернуты в класс `.container` с `width: 90%;` а сами блоки построены на flexbox c `justify-content: space-between;` - таким образом все элементы страницы соответственно подгоняются под размер окна браузера а скролл стоит на `overflow-x: hidden;` :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: стоит ли так заморачиваться или же просто указать фиксированную ширину body как на stackoverflow? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: При горизонтальном скролле страница не считается адаптивной. Конечно стоит заморачиваться, если ты поднял вопрос про адаптивность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте по порядку:

1. Страница **считается** адаптивной, когда в `<head>` прописан `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. С этого момента все роботы будут считать страницу адаптивной под мобильные устройства.
2. Не думаю, что заказчик или кто-либо еще оценит горизонтальный скролл на странице. Писать `overflow-x: hidden` - костыльно, ибо нужно разбираться, из-за каких именно блоков появляется горизонтальный скролл, а не рубить все с плеча.

Если говорить про фикс. ширину SO, то зайдите на него с мобильного устройства и Вам откроется мобильная версия. Тут дело в другом, адаптация происходит в переадресации на другой адрес, а не на самом SO.

Answer (score -1):

Страница не адаптивная, если можно скроллить. 
Я вместо `width = 90%` использую `html,body{overflow-x:hidden}` и не забываю в `head` html-документа прописать `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. Таким образом ширина документа приравнивается ширине экрана любого устройства и проблем в горизонтальной прокруткой не возникает (если элементы не выпирают). При `width = 90%` неудобно задавать размеры, если они не относительные.